# Multiple Sequelize Associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a few associations between models like so:

```
Patient.hasMany(Transaction, {
    as: 'transactions',
    foreignKey: 'patient_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});

Transaction.belongsTo(Patient, {
    as: 'patient',
    foreignKey: 'patient_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});

Transaction.hasMany(Transaction, {
    as: 'transactions',
    foreignKey: 'item_to_pay',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
```

I'm writing a query to get a list of transactions that belong to a patient and include the models associated with them:

```
Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
        patient_id: 1
    },
    include: [{
        model: Patient,
        as: 'patient',
        attributes: ['first_name']
    }, {
        model: Transaction,
        as: 'transactions',
        include: [{
            model: Patient,
            as: 'patient',
            attributes: ['first_name']
        }]
    }],
});
```

However when the result returns, it does not include the second nested patient model as I expect it to.

I've also tried writing a different query to see if I can get the desired result:

```
Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
        patient_id: 1
    },
    include: [{
        model: Transaction,
        as: 'transactions',
        include: [{
            model: Patient,
            as: 'patient',
            attributes: ['first_name']
        }]
    }],
});
```

But this query errors out and returns 'Unknown column 'patient.id' in field list'.

Does anyone see something wrong with my query or associations? Is there something I'm not understanding about the associations here?

Comment: try to add the `id` attribute to `attributes: ['first_name']`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, got the same results though.

Comment: try to add `subQuery: false` in root options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my original query since I couldn't figure it out at the time. I stumbled into the same issue recently and realized the issue came from how I named my associations. I named the `transaction.hasMany` association as `transactions` which ended up confusing MySQL with the query that was generated because one of the tables is named transactions.

TLDR, don't name your associations the same name as any of your table names.